# How to transform an array of objects?

Tags: javascript

I have array of objects

```
[
    {
        "store_name":"ABC",
        "store_iput": "123",
        "store_Amount": "34"
    },
    {
        "store_name":"XYZ",
        "store_iput": "178",
        "store_Amount": "346"
    },
    {
        "store_name":"Tokr",
        "store_iput": "3",
        "store_Amount": "3"
    }
]
```

All three object has same keys but with different values.So I want only keys with all the values.

```
{
    "store_name":["ABC","XYZ","Tokr"],
    "store_input":["123","178","3"],
    "store_Amount":["34","346","3"]
}
```

How to get this output?

Comment: Is your output supposed to be a single object with three properties that are each arrays? (You've not put `{}` around it.) Also, your input isn't quite a valid array format in that the elements aren't separated by commas and has some quote characters in not quite the right places.

Comment: You should try to write more descriptive question titles. See [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 2):

## Brief way

```
let result={};
Object.keys(array[0]).forEach((key)=>{
           result[key]=array.map((e)=> e[key]);
})
```

## [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/abdennour/75t4bo9o/1/)

Comment: very elegant, I got stuck with quirksmode at work for such a long time, its great to see how the language has evolved.

Comment: Greater than , to see the language can be used also in Back-end (NodeJS,..so on).. @Steve Nice to meet u .

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you, the simplest way for you to get similar thing is store all values in an array.

For example you can use for loop:

```
var i, store_name, store_input, store_Amount, array;

array = [
    {
        "store_name":"ABC",
        "store_iput": "123",
        "store_Amount": "34"
    },
    {
        "store_name":"XYZ",
        "store_iput": "178",
        "store_Amount": "346"
    },
    {
        "store_name":"Tokr",
        "store_iput": "3",
        "store_Amount": "3"
    }
]

for(i=0;i<array.length;i++){
    store_name[i]=array[i].store_name;
    store_input[i]=array[i].store_name;
    store_Amount[i]=array[i].store_name;
}
```

And than, you gets 3 arrays of values - store names, store inputs and store amounts.

If you are determined to store all values in one object you can do following instead of previous for loop:

```
var obj = {
    var store_name = [],
        store_input= [],
        store_Amount = [];
};

for(i=0;i<array.length;i++){
    obj.store_name[i]=array[i].store_name;
    obj.store_input[i]=array[i].store_name;
    obj.store_Amount[i]=array[i].store_name;
}
```

Comment: you need to look back over your code...there are some copy paste issues

Comment: the brief answer is  : http://stackoverflow.com/a/38448527/747579

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it:

```js
var input = [
  { "store_name": "ABC", "store_iput": "123", "store_Amount": "34" },
  { "store_name": "XYZ", "store_iput": "178", "store_Amount": "346" },
  { "store_name": "Tokr", "store_iput": "3", "store_Amount": "3" }
];

var output = input.reduce(function(a, v) {
  Object.keys(v).forEach(function(k) { (a[k] || (a[k] = [])).push(v[k]); });
  return a;
}, {});

console.log(output);
```

Further reading:

- [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)
- [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)
- [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/ForEach)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Object.keys` to get the names of the keys in the first object of the array, then iterate over this array, using `Array#map` to get the mapped values from all the object, and adding the mapped values to a new object for each key:

```
var keys = Object.keys(objectArray[0]);
var combinedObject = {};
keys.forEach(function(key){
    combinedObject[key] = objectArray.map(function(object){
        return object[key];
    });
})
```

Comment: the brief answer is  : http://stackoverflow.com/a/38448527/747579

Answer (score 0):

```js
(function(arr) {
  var rtn = {};
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    for (var k in arr[i]) {
      if (rtn[k]) {
        rtn[k].push(arr[i][k]);
      } else {
        rtn[k] = [arr[i][k]];
      }
    }
  }
  console.log(rtn)
  return rtn;

})([{
  "store_name": "ABC",
  "store_iput": "123",
  "store_Amount": "34"
}, {
  "store_name": "XYZ",
  "store_iput": "178",
  "store_Amount": "346"
}, {
  "store_name": "Tokr",
  "store_iput": "3",
  "store_Amount": "3"
}]);
```

Comment: the brief answer is  : http://stackoverflow.com/a/38448527/747579

Answer (score 0):

Just iterate the array items. For each one, get its properties and iterate them. Use the property as the key where to store the data in the results. If the key doesn't exist, create a new array.

```js
var data = [
  {
    "store_name":"ABC",
    "store_iput": "123",
    "store_Amount": "34"
  },
  {
    "store_name":"XYZ",
    "store_iput": "178",
    "store_Amount": "346"
  },
  {
    "store_name":"Tokr",
    "store_iput": "3",
    "store_Amount": "3"
  }
];
console.log(data.reduce(function(result, item, index) {
  Object.keys(item).forEach(function(key) {
    if(!result.hasOwnProperty(key)) result[key] = new Array(data.length);
    result[key][index] = item[key];
  });
  return result;
}, {}));
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple approaches to this problem, as listed by others.

If you are looking at solving it using `ECMA5` syntax then you can use `reduce`.

**Example:**

```
var test =
[
    {
        "store_name":"ABC,",
        "store_input": "123",
        "store_Amount": "34"
    },
    {
        "store_name":"XYZ",
        "store_input": "178",
        "store_Amount": "346"
    },
    {
        "store_name":"Tokr",
        "store_input": "3",
        "store_Amount": "3"
    }
];

let output = test.reduce((accumulator, current) => {
    accumulator.store_name.push(current.store_name);
    accumulator.store_input.push(current.store_input);
    accumulator.store_Amount.push(current.store_Amount);
    return accumulator
}, {
    "store_name" : [],
    "store_input" : [],
    "store_Amount" : []
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(output));
```

**Output:**

```
{
    "store_name":["ABC,","XYZ","Tokr"],
    "store_input":["123","178","3"],
    "store_Amount":["34","346","3"]
}
```

Essentially what the code is doing there is it is trying to use your JSON object `test` and reduce it into a single object populated with keys; `store_name`, `store_input` and `store_amount`. Where each one of those has an array. See the 2nd parameter of `reduce`.

Then for each iteration in the the `reduce` API, the code will retrieve the appropriate properties from `current` and push its value into the right array. And it goes on until the iteration is over.

You might also want to check out the other usages for `reduce`.

**See:**
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

Comment: the brief answer is  : http://stackoverflow.com/a/38448527/747579

Answer (score 0):

Its easy if you know all the keys before hand.

```
var data = {
   store_name:[],
   store_input:[],
   store_Amount:[]
}

items.forEach(function(el, i, arr){
   data.store_name.push(el.store_name);
   data.store_input.push(el.store_input);
   data.store_Amount.push(el.store_Amount);       
} 
// or
items.forEach(function(el, i, arr){
   Object.keys(el).forEach(function(key) {
       data[key].push(el[key]);
   });       
}
```

If you need to account for new or missing keys, then you'll need to dynamically add the keys to the data object and then post process to sync the key array lengths if desired

```
var data = {};
items.forEach(function(el, i, arr){
    Object.keys(el).forEach(function(key) {
       var arr = data[key] || [];
       arr[i] = el[key]; // set to i to account for missing values
       data[key] = arr;
    }
}
// resize any short arrays
// fill in missing data?
Object.keys(data).forEach(function(key){
    data[key].length = items.length;
});
```

Comment: the brief answer is  : http://stackoverflow.com/a/38448527/747579

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct way to achieve the desired output.
You need to do some calculation to achieve it. Try to use the following:

```
var arr = [{"store_name":"ABC", "store_iput": "123", "store_Amount": "34" }, {"store_name":"XYZ", "store_iput": "178", "store_Amount": "346"}, {"store_name":"Tokr", "store_iput": "3", "store_Amount": "3"}]
var result= {};
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    var obj = arr[i];
    for (var prop in obj) {
        if (result[prop] == null) {
            result[prop] = [];
            result[prop].push(obj[prop]);
        } else {
            result[prop].push(obj[prop]);
        }
    }
}

for (var prop in result) {
    // you need to use print statement to print key and value
}
```

Comment: the brief answer is  : http://stackoverflow.com/a/38448527/747579

Answer (score 0):

```
var final = {store_name: [], store_iput: [], store_Amount: []}
var original = [
    {
        "store_name":"ABC",
        "store_iput": "123",
        "store_Amount": "34"
    },
    {
        "store_name":"XYZ",
        "store_iput": "178",
        "store_Amount": "346"
    },
    {
        "store_name":"Tokr",
        "store_iput": "3",
        "store_Amount": "3"
    }
]

original.forEach(function(x){
    final.store_name.push(x.store_name)
    final.store_iput.push(x.store_iput)
    final.store_Amount.push(x.store_Amount)
})
```

https://repl.it/CdX5/1

Comment: the brief answer is  : http://stackoverflow.com/a/38448527/747579